# Facebook-sdk python module has no attribute GraphAPI

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

After installing the facebook-sdk module [here](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html), and looking at other solutions here and elsewhere, I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "facebook.py", line 1, in <module>
    import facebook
  File "/home/facebook/facebook.py", line 3, in <module>
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='ACCESS TOKEN HERE')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GraphAPI'
```

For this very simple python code to authenticate...

```
import facebook

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='ACCESS TOKEN HERE')

print 'Workinnnn'
```

It says my module is installed and up to date, and I have installed both within (as suggested) a virtualenv and outside, and still get the error. I also definitely HAVE the module in usr/local/lib/python etc. dist packages... and it contains the class GraphAPI

Has anyone got a suggestion either:

1) What might be going wrong?
2) What to try to fix it? UNinstall something?
3) If there is another way other than pip to install the module... I don't normally use pip (but definitely have it installed and installed facebook-sdk from it) so if there's another way then I'd like to try...

Cheers :/

Answer (score 5):

Solution = don't name your script the same as your module.

I'm an idiot, sigh...

Comment: did the same thing as you haha

Comment: There are more idiots out there --blush-- Thx for posting this!

Comment: I am stuck on the same error: graph = facebook.GraphAPI(ACCESS_TOKEN)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GraphAPI'    -> Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)  Ubuntu

Comment: I tested: "from facebook import GraphAPI" on prompt and there is no error!

Comment: print facebook.__path__
-> /root/facebookenv/src/facebook-sdk/facebook

Comment: print facebook.GraphAPI
<class 'facebook.GraphAPI'>
What is wrong?